# What is the story of Kumara Swamy or Kartikeya taking the form of Subrahmanya (snake)?

Tags: puranas, kartikeya

Kumara Swamy or Kartikeya is also worshipped as Subrahmanya swamy (snake form). What is the story behind taking this form? Which Purana states it?

Comment: Do you know etymology of word "Subramanya"?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes. Su + Brahmanya, I know that, but I heard that there is a story behind taking this form, which happened near Srisailam, that he married the daughter of a chenchu (who also happened to be the daughter of Kumuda, son of Adisesha). So Where does this story come from? Which purana states it?

Comment: I heard a similar story of Vasuki acquiring boon from Kumara Swamy that whoever worship Vasuki or Nagendra will get blessings of Subramanya too. BTW, i heard that Shiva married a Chechu girl and even those people consider Shiva as their Son-in-law.

Comment: So, What is the story behind taking this form and what is the source?

Comment: I don't know proper story and where it is mentioned. What is meaning of **Brahmanya**?

Comment: Su + Brahmanya = very dear to brahmins (Those who are brahma jnanis)

Comment: As far as I know Muruga is never worshipped as a snake. Lord Shiva is worshipped as Nageshvara. So maybe there is some confusion as to whether it is Lord Shiva or Muruga.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Mopidevi Subramanya Swami temple](http://www.mopidevitemple.org/index.html) of Andhra Pradesh, the story of Kumara Swamy turning into snake is mentioned in [Sahyadri Khanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahyadrikhanda) of Skanda MahaPurana. You can read Sthala Purana from [here](http://www.mopidevitemple.org/images/swamy-book.pdf) (in telugu).

Sahyadri Khanda mentions legends of temples on the bank of River Krishna. You can read Sahyadri Khanda in Sanskrit from [here](https://archive.org/details/Sahyadri-Khanda).

Temple [website](http://www.mopidevitemple.org/aboutus.html) describes the story in English as follows :

> Four Deva Rishis viz., Sankara, Sanakasa, Sanatkumara, and Sanatsujata
>   are known for their un-wavering devotion and saintly knowledge. They
>   are immortal and always appear at the age of five years to others. They
>   remained so detached from the awareness of worldly matters that they
>   remain naked without covering their bodies. Once, they came to Kailas,
>   the abode of Lord Shiva to worship Him. At the same time, Sachi Devi,
>   Swaha Devi, Goddess Saraswathi and Goddess Lakshmi also arrived. Lord
>   Subrahmanyeswara was sitting in the lap of his mother Goddess Parvathi
>   by that time. Lord Subrahmanyeswara as a child was bewildered at the
>   two contrasts of fully clad Gods and Goddesses on one hand and the
>   nude Deva rishis on the other. He giggled innocently in a childish
>   way. Goddess Parvathi chided Lord Subrahmanyeswara for his folly.
>   Later, Lord Subrahmanyeswara realised his lapse and took permission to
>   do penance to get rid of the blemish. **Lord Subrahmanyeswara did the
>   penance in disguise, in the form of a snake for many years and
>   successfully cleansed Himself of his folly.** The place where Lord
>   Subrahmanyeswara did penance later came to be known as ‘Mopidevi’.

Comment: Dr. Vaddiparti Padmakar says a different story in Dharma Sandehalu here https://youtu.be/Vg9ShcZEm9w?t=3m18s

Comment: @Student i can't understand Sanskrit. Can you see whether Mopidevi story is available in Sahyadri Khanda? if not, Temple authorities might have slightly different version of Sahyadri Khanda.

Comment: @Student I think Kumara Swamy can take any form at His will. But first time might be  when he was child as above story mentions he was kid.