# Manas Khanda, Sahyadri Khanda of Skanda Purana

Tags: skanda-purana

Are there any available manuscripts of Manasa, Sahyadri, Himavat, Patala, Ayodhya, Bhima, Mathura Khandas of Skanda Purana either in Sanskrit or any language?

Comment: My answer for your [Subramanya swamy](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14256/3500) question has link for Sahyadri Kanda (Sanskrit).

Comment: Thank You. What about other Khandas? Are there any resources available?

Comment: I am also trying to get manuscripts for these khandas. Looks like there are two variants of Skanda Purana - one found in India, and other found in Nepal. The popular Skhanda Purana is covering only seven khanas - Maheśvara, Viṣṇu or Vaiṣṇava, Brahma, Kāśī, Āvantya, Nāgara and Prabhāsa. If you had any success in getting above khandas please let me know.

Comment: @Ravi I have the Skanda Purana with all the seven khandas. If you would like to have a copy, please mail me.